# Linker error "cannot find -l/some/path/libfilename"

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have set up eclipse in windows and tried to compile a simple code related to a POS device but i get error the code is:

```
#include <posapi.h>
#include <printer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

printf ("Beeping...");
beep(100,2000);
printf("Stop Beeping.");

return 0;
}
```

and the error is:

```
cannot find -l/cygdrive/d/Docs/SDK/SDK/Windows/sdk-new8210-1.0.0/sdk/lib/libpos.so
```

---

[update from comment]

This is the command line:

```
/cygdrive/c/glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -I"C:\cygwin\usr\include" -I"D:\Docs\SDK\SDK\Windows\sdk-new8210-1.0.0\sdk\include" -I"D:\Docs\SDK\SDK\Windows\sdk-new8210-1.0.0\sdk\include\directfb" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -marm -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -MMD -MP -MF"src/DemoApp5.d" -MT"src/DemoApp5.d" -o "src/DemoApp5.o" "../src/DemoApp5.c"
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Could you show us the command line?

Comment: this is the command line: /cygdrive/c/glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -I"C:\cygwin\usr\include" -I"D:\Docs\SDK\SDK\Windows\sdk-new8210-1.0.0\sdk\include" -I"D:\Docs\SDK\SDK\Windows\sdk-new8210-1.0.0\sdk\include\directfb" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -marm -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -MMD -MP -MF"src/DemoApp5.d" -MT"src/DemoApp5.d" -o "src/DemoApp5.o" "../src/DemoApp5.c"

Comment: Are you sure with this command line, as there is not use of `-l`  in there.

Answer (score 1):

The linker option `-l` does not specify a libray by "path/filename", but by its name only. That is the file name with the leading "lib" chopped of. In your case it would be

```
-lpos
```

To additionally specify a search path the option `-L` is used (prior to the refering `-l`option). So in you case this might be:

```
-Ld/Docs/SDK/SDK/Windows/sdk-new8210-1.0.0/sdk/lib/ -lpos
```

(`-L` and `-l` may be used multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the `-l` flag for specifying libraries to link against. Use:

```
-L /cygdrive/d/Docs/SDK/SDK/Windows/sdk-new8210-1.0.0/sdk/lib/ -lpos
```

instead. `-L` specifies additional locations where to look for libraries and `-l` specifies the name of the library (without the initial `lib...`).

Comment: i changed it now i get this error:

Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
/cygdrive/c/glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -static -L/cygdrive/d/Docs/SDK/SDK/Windows/sdk-new8210-1.0.0/sdk/lib/ -marm -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -Wl,-Map,"C:\Users\Saba rayaneh\workspace-cpp\DemoApp5\Debug\DemoApp5.map" -o "DemoApp5"  ./src/DemoApp5.o   -lpos
/cygdrive/c/glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: **cannot find -lpos**
collect2: ld returned 1

Comment: Probably you have to adjust the `-L /cygdrive/d/Docs/SDK/SDK/Windows/sdk-new8210-1.0.0/sdk/lib/` part with a correct path. Try using the windows path (i.e. starting with `C:\`) the the `lib` directory and doublecheck that `libpos.so` is in there.

Comment: i used windows-style path : -Ld:\Docs\SDK\SDK\Windows\sdk-new8210-1.0.0\sdk\lib\ but i got same error